# Assigning columns to a hierarchical higher Multiindex level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like this:

```
   Ax  Ay  Bx  By
0   1  20   2  20
1   3  21   5  22
2   4  20   7  25
```

and I want to manually define that Ax and Ay have the hierarchical higher MultiIndex level of A (and also do the same for B). So that the dataframe looks like this:

```
   A      B
   x   y  x   y
0  1  20  2  20
1  3  21  5  22
2  4  20  7  25
```

So what I'm looking for is a statement that says:

Ax and Ay go under A as x and y

Comment: how are A and x distinguished in your columns? is it literally the first and second character, or something more complex?

Comment: No its actually the first characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually construct a [`pandas.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) using one of several constructors. From the docs:

- [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays)
  Convert list of arrays to MultiIndex.
- [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product)
  Create a MultiIndex from the cartesian product of iterables.
- [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples)
  Convert list of tuples to a MultiIndex.
- [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame)
  Make a MultiIndex from a DataFrame.

All of these are useful and I'd check them each out to understand their use cases. For your case, I think `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` might do the trick:

```py
In [4]: list_of_split_tuples = list(map(tuple, df.columns.values))

In [5]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list_of_split_tuples)

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   A      B
   x   y  x   y
0  1  20  2  20
1  3  21  5  22
2  4  20  7  25
```

Answer (score 5):

Via `split()` and `droplevel()`:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('([A-Z])',expand=True).droplevel(0)
```

**OR**

Via `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays()`:

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','A','B','B'],['x','y','x','y']])
```

Output of `df`:

```
   A      B
   x   y  x   y
0  1  20  2  20
1  3  21  5  22
2  4  20  7  25
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use regex and `split` with `expand=True` parameter:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('(?<=[A-Z])', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
   A      B    
   x   y  x   y
0  1  20  2  20
1  3  21  5  22
2  4  20  7  25
```